# How to draw a plot with marks and vertical lines in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw a plot consisting of marks and vertical lines connecting the marks with the horizontal axis. The closest I could invent so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1, xmax=4,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.5
]
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o]
    coordinates{(0,0)(0,0.5^3)};
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o]
    coordinates{(1,0)(1,3*0.5^3)};
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o]
    coordinates{(2,0)(2,3*0.5^3)};
\addplot[color=blue, mark=o]
    coordinates{(3,0)(3,0.5^3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which is bad because

- I don't want marks on horizontal axis.
- I don't want lines showing inside marks.
- I would prefer to have a single `\addplot` command instead of many.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.  Help us help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I have understood your question right, but did you mean the following?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1, xmax=4,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.5,
        ycomb,             % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot+ [mark options={fill=white}] coordinates {
            (0,0.5^3)
            (1,3*0.5^3)
            (2,3*0.5^3)
            (3,0.5^3)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I think also `mark=*,mark options={fill=white}`, cf. the second point.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., aah, that was meant. Then you are absolutely right. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, `ycomb` and `\addplot[mark=*,mark options={fill=white}, ...]` solved it.